# Compute probability of $XY=c$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, proof-writing, random-variables

> Let be $(\Omega,\mathcal{P}(\Omega),P)$ a discrete probability space, $X$ and $Y$ two discrete random variables, where $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$, $Y:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ and $c\in\mathbb{Q}$. $P_X$ and $P_Y$ are the associated probability distributions.
>
> 1.) Find $P(XY=c)$.
>
> 2.) How can you further simplify if $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

---

**My approach:**

We denote the joint probability distribution by $P_{XY}$, then
$$
P(XY=c)=\sum\limits_{(x,y)\in X(\Omega)\times Y(\Omega)~\mid~ xy=c}P_{XY}(X=x,Y=y).
$$
If $c\neq 0$, then $x\neq 0$ and
$$
\sum\limits_{(x,y)\in X(\Omega)\times Y(\Omega)~\mid~ xy=c}P_{XY}(X=x,Y=y)= \sum\limits_{x\in X(\Omega)~\mid ~\frac{c}{x}\in Y(\Omega)}P_{XY}\left(X=x,Y=\frac{c}{x}\right).
$$
If $c=0$, then $x=0\lor y=0$
$$
\sum\limits_{(x,y)\in X(\Omega)\times Y(\Omega)~\mid~ xy=c}P_{XY}(X=x,Y=y)=P_{XY}(X=0,Y=0)+\sum\limits_{(0,y)\in X(\Omega)\times Y(\Omega)}P_{XY}(X=0,Y=y)+\sum\limits_{(x,0)\in X(\Omega)\times Y(\Omega)}P_{XY}(X=x,Y=0).
$$

Regarding 2.):

Under the assuption of independence we can simply split up the joint probability in both cases at the end and get:
$$
= \sum\limits_{x\in X(\Omega)~\mid ~\frac{c}{x}\in Y(\Omega)}P_{X}(X=x)P_Y\left(Y=\frac{c}{x}\right)
$$
and
$$
= P_{X}(X=0)P_Y(Y=0)+\sum\limits_{(0,y)\in X(\Omega)\times Y(\Omega)}P_{X}(X=0)P_Y(Y=y)+\sum\limits_{(x,0)\in X(\Omega)\times Y(\Omega)}P_{X}(X=x)P_Y(Y=0).
$$

---

Is this correct? I am not quite sure if this is what the professor wants us to do?

Comment: Could it have something to do with that c being a rational number? Could P(XY = c) be 0?

Comment: Considering the given probability space, I guess it is not necessary 0. But I presume you should try to work with the form c = p/q, where p and q are integers.